# How do I programmatically check EFFECTIVE delete (modify) or write permissions in .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-permissions

Sorry in advance for the long question.
What I'm really interested in is a way to programmatically check if the executing windows identity has adequate windows privileges to write to a directory (or file) in an ASP.NET web services application. But I'll settle for retrieving effective delete (modify) privileges for a user for a given directory or file.  The problem is that I would like to be able to do this without either writing temporary files OR necessarily performing the IO action and handling the exception.

Yes, there is a question on this already ( see [How can I programmatically determine if I have write privileges using C# in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137031/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-i-have-write-privileges-using-c-in-net))
Normally I would agree with the accepted answer that the best method is to just try the IO action and handle any exceptions -- System.IO methods do throw System.UnauthorizedAccessException to indicate failure as a result of privilege denial.  But in the case of of UPLOADING files, I'd really like to check the privileges BEFORE wasting the time and resources of uploading the data since it is only AFTER upload that we can attempt to write the file or folder in question.  I pity any users uploading a 2GB file over http only to be told after the upload completes that they don't have permissions to upload the file to the destination.

The usual approach to testing write access if you don't want to perform the actual write is to write a temporary file.  The other question has an answer pointing this out.  This is what our code currently does.  BUT windows security allows write access without delete privileges. Users with ONLY write access but no delete end up leaving all sorts of undeleted .tmp files.  And no, we don't want to use a Domain admin account to reset the ACL on the tmp files and then delete them. The approach I've been taking is to check if the user has write privileges using System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(..) or System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(..) and dealing with the various access rules and ACE returns... but with this I still have issues dealing with EFFECTIVE privileges -- i.e. in most cases I also have to look up the user's membership in any of the groups listed in the ACE that do have permissions on the object.  There has to be an easier way.... doesn't there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well kudos for going the extra mile on user experience AND trying to maintain clean program structure. Maybe if you're uploading only you could try to create an empty 'placeholder' file with the same name as the final 2GB file will have, then just overwrite it. Not perfect since you could still end up with an empty file, but pretty easy and at least a little bit more elegant that some of the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have permanent file, say 'access_test.txt', which you try to overwrite with a datestamp or something to first to test the current access.